# Can't use serverChangeToken in CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation

Tags: swift, token, cloudkit

In recordZoneFetchCompletionBlock I am getting serverChangeToken, and official Apple documentation says about serverChangeToken it returns:

> serverChangeToken
> The current server change token to be stored and used in subsequent CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation instances.

But there is no any token property in CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation, no such parameter in its constructor. How can I pass serverChangeToken into the CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance of `ZoneConfiguration` and assign the saved token to `previousServerChangeToken`

```
let options = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation.ZoneConfiguration()
options.previousServerChangeToken = zoneChangeToken
```

and pass the options in the `configurationsByRecordZoneID` parameter

`zoneChangeToken` represents the *current server change token to be stored*